# Meaning of dup2() POSIX function with second argument equals Zero

Tags: c, linux, function, unix, posix

Sometimes I see strange usage of `dup2()` function. For example:

```
    if ((sock= accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&s_addr, &namelen)) == -1){
                syslog(LOG_ERR, "in accept: %m");
                exit(3);

    }
            dup2(sock, 0);
            close(sockfd);
            sock = 0;
```

It doesn't even check the return value. What exactly does it do with such arguments? The `man dup2` says that if `newfd (second argument of dup2) was previously open, it is silently closed before being reused.` But the 0 is stdin and why do we even need to do that?

Comment: What if you want your program to behave as if stdin was from the socket itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a fairly-common paradigm to configure a program to operate on a socket as the standard input.

By itself it probably seems pointless - why not just operate on whatever the socket descriptor is? - but in practice it's almost always followed by a `fork()` operation that runs some child process that expects to read from standard input.

*Poof* - now it works with the socket.

Likely you'll see stdout manipulated in a similar way.

EDIT: A super simple example is a network service that offers you a shell after you accept a TCP connection:

```
    ...
    if ((sock= accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&s_addr, &namelen)) == -1){
        syslog(LOG_ERR, "in accept: %m");
        exit(3);
    }
    dup2(sock, 0); // stdin
    dup2(sock, 1); // stdout
    dup2(sock, 2); // stderr
    close(sock);

    system("/bin/sh");  // terrible security
```

So now when you connect to it - perhaps with telnet from a client - you have sort-of a shell that has what appears to be traditional stdin/out/err, all connected to the socket.

The point is you see this mainly used only when some *child process* has to be executed, where it assumes file descriptors 0/1/2 are set up in a certain way.

NOTE: this is a terrible idea and **highly** insecure, and the only time you ever see this for real is in malware.  I hesitated to include the example here, but it's such a clear illustration that I thought it worth it.

Comment: I think I begin to understand, but could you provide any simple example on C with explanation for me? (Not sure if I **really** understand:))
I mean, what can I do after dup2(sock, 0)? If I understanding right, stdin after dup2 is the same thing as sock. Is that right?

Comment: And after that we can write to stdin and in fact we will write to the socket as it's a duplicate of `sock`. But what's the point of this? Why not just write to `sock`? Why do we need to replace the `stdin` by `sock`?

Comment: @kekyc - I've updated my answer with an example. The short answer is you only really do this if you need to interact with child processes that expect their input/output set up in a certain way. Without this child-process consideration, you're right that there'd be no point.